# combobox contain subfolder never created or seen

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

i have a textbox (name_f) and combobox (name_sf) , i want when the user types the folder name, automatically the list of sub-folders appears in the combobox . But , my problem is : the combobox contains subfolders never seen or created,

can someone help me?

my code is in vb.net and i use google drive api

this is my code (i call this code in another method)

```
Public Function lists(folder As String) As List(Of String)
 Dim liste As New List(Of String)
        ' declaration d un tableau ou liste de string lst
        Dim lister = Service.Files.List()
        lister.Q = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
        Dim exec = lister.Execute()
        For Each parcour In exec.Items
            If (parcour.Title = folder) Then
                Dim lister_s = Service.Files.List()
                lister_s.Q = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder '"
                Dim result = lister_s.Execute()
                For Each parcour_s In result.Items
                    liste.Add(parcour_s.Title)
                Next
            End If
        Next
        Return liste
End Function
```

Comment: Is the `TextBox` associated with the `ComboBox` or kept separately? See if the api is being called perfectly.

Comment: yes api is called perfectly , my problem is : i see the correct subfolder , but also i found another subfolder never created or seen before . 
I explain : i have a folder contain 3 subfolder in drive , when i type the folder name , i think found 3 subfolder in combobox ...but i found the 3 correct subfolder and another list of subfolder

Comment: Are any of them subfolders of the folders you are finding?  Is it possibly recursive?